# C++ Builder XE3, IntraWeb, Display SQL Server database query results

Tags: c++, sql, c++builder, delphi-xe3, intraweb

Our company is beginning development on an IntraWeb application which requires access to our SQL Server database(s). I am attempting to creating a very basic application to get one column of data from our database and display it... in any way possible. I have attempted many times to do this but have only seen failure. From what I see I can not even get query results. I am using C++ Builder XE3. This is what I am doing...

- Create IntraWeb Application Wizard (Standalone)
- Add #include "UserSessionUnit.h" to Unit1.cpp
- Set IWServerController->ComInitialization to ciMultiThreaded
- Drag TADOConnection to UserSessionUnit
- Set ADOConnection1->ConnectionString using builder (Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server)
- Drag TADOQuery to UserSessionUnit
- Set ADOQuery1->Connection to ADOConnection1
- Set ADOQuery1->SQL to "SELECT Column1 FROM Table1"
- Drag TDataSource to UserSessionUnit
- Set DataSource1->DataSet to ADOQuery1
- Drag TIWDBGrid to Unit1
- Set IWDBGrid1->DataSource to IWUserSession.DataSource1
- Run the query when IWForm1 is created...

`void __fastcall TIWForm1::IWAppFormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
UserSession()->ADOQuery1->Open();
}`

I imagine this should work. The application builds and runs with no errors, but displays only an empty grid...
I replicated this scenario in a C++ Builder VCL Forms Application and it worked no problems (used TDBGrid instead of TIWDBGrid, of course).
I have tried this with several "TIWDB" components to no avail.

Comment: Did you see any exception raised? In debug you can see if your DataSet actually have records after opening it, did you tried that?